# one Activity color is looking different,like yellowish shade In the whole app . Is there any idea why it looks like that?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-background

Please give some suggestion . I don't know how to change this.
I have given white color background #FFFFFF. But it looks like yellowish shade,not a perfect white. 
This is updated question check and let me give some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

First Screen:

[image: This is a yellowish screen]

Second Screen:

[image: Actual white color screen]

Code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
          android:tag="cards main container"
    android:background="@color/background_grey"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="#FEFEFE"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FEFEFE"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="left">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:tag="image_tag"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_default_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                <com.nowfloats.CustomWidget.roboto_lt_45_505050
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Large Text"/>

                <com.nowfloats.CustomWidget.roboto_md_36__565656
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Medium Text"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try #FEFEFE instead of #FFFFFF.

Comment: Can you post the XML code of the layout and a screenshot?

Comment: FEFEFE also not working

Comment: Does it look yellowish on device or in the emulator?

Comment: in device its looking yellowish

Comment: its strange issue...please help me